# No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql in IntellJ with MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, sql, database, exception

I work with IntellJ
So I have this code (*Username and Password changed*):

```
    String jdbcUrl = "jdbc:mysql://sql11.freesqldatabase.com:3306/sql11418144";
    String username = "user1234";
    String password = "abc";

    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(jdbcUrl, username, password);
    Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
    String url = "select name from table";
    ResultSet result = stmt.executeQuery(url);

    while (result.next()) {
        System.out.println(result.getString("name"));
    }
```

I use MySQL and I have these configurations:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tDkpB.png)

But I have this Error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://........
```

What can I do? I can run SELECT COMMANDS in IntellJ but not with JAVA??

Comment: I'm not an expert, but have you added the MySQL JDBC driver in the lib folder?

Comment: I can run SELECT COMMANDS in IntellJ but not with JAVA??, Its because IntellJ has the mysql driver installed, but your project doesn't. Add the mysql driver to your pom.xml and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Your connection string looks okay.  I'm assuming you're using maven to build. If so, do you have the following in your .pom file or included in your project? https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
</dependency>
```